# EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP in Mozilla firefox extention

Tags: browser, cross-browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-security-policy

My chrome extension is working fine and i want to make it compatible with Firefox as well. In the extension i have used eval method that is throwing error "EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP".

I tried to add below configuration in the manifest 3 file but still getting the CSP issue. ('wasm-unsafe-eval' is also not working.)

"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"
}

Comment: In most situations, the goal can be achieved without using `eval()` which is blocked for security reasons.